# Django Slice isn't working on a zip

Tags: python, django, zip, slice

I've been tinkering with Django and Python recently, and while trying to limit a for loop in my code, I've noticed that the slice function isn't working.

What I'm trying to do is scrape data from a gig listing website (I have permission), and list the next 5 gig listings on my own site. The data scraping in views.py does work fine, but returns ~40 results. I've tried using |slice:":5" to trim the for loop in my HTML, but it doesn't seem to work, and still displays all 40 listings.

Is it possible to use slice with a zip of arrays? Is there a better way to do it?

**HTML**

```
{% for dates, venuelinks, venues, times in gig|slice:":5" %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{dates}}</li>
        <li><a href="{{venuelinks}}">{{venues}}</a></li>
        <li>{{times}}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

**Views.py method**

```
response = requests.get($URL) #anonymised for stackoverflow
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

dates = [x.text for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
venues = [x.text for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
venuelinks = [x.attrs.get('href') for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
times = [x.text for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]     
gigs = zip(dates, venuelinks, venues, times)

t = loader.get_template('index.html')
html = t.render({'gig': gigs})  
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option may be to slice the original lists directly:

```
response = requests.get($URL) #anonymised for stackoverflow
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

dates = [x.text for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
venues = [x.text for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
venuelinks = [x.attrs.get('href') for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
times = [x.text for x in soup.select('$CONDITION')]
gigs = zip(dates[:5], venuelinks[:5], venues[:5], times[:5])

t = loader.get_template('index.html')
html = t.render({'gig': gigs})  
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Please see @f43d65 answer for explanation, why your current setup fails "silently"... And consider doing as few operations as possible in the templates and most of the dirty work inside of the view functions.

Comment: This worked great thanks! I hadn't done any work with zips before, and wasn't aware I couldn't use slice.

Comment: @CameronD17 You could further improve the function with making the slice size variable, so your users may decide if they want to see 5 or 10 events. I guess you can take it from here by your own! Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python3 then you can't slice zips. You could try converting the zip to a list with:

```
>>> gigs = list(zip(dates, venuelinks, venues, times))
```

But this will defeat many of the purposes of slicing like not generating large sets of data in the first place. However, as you're creating lists already I guess that's not a huge issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using slicing on zip object raises TypeError. In this case `slice` template filter fails silently and returns initial value https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L622-L623 .